# Add null as value when element does not exist in XML file C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

In C# I'm using the following to get some elements from an XML file:

```
var TestCaseDescriptions = doc.SelectNodes("//testcase/htmlcomment");
```

This works fine and gets the correct information but when my testcase has no htmlcomment it won't add any entry in the XmlNodeList TestCaseDescriptions.

When there's not htmlcomment I would like to have the value "null" as string the TestCaseDescriptions. So in the end I would have an XMLNodeList like

> htmlcomment
>
> htmlcomment
>
> null
>
> htmlcomment
>
> htmlcomment

Can anyone describe or create a sample how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var TestCaseDescriptions = doc.SelectNodes("//testcase/htmlcomment");
> ```
>
> When there's not htmlcomment I would like to have the value "null" as string the TestCaseDescriptions.

Your problem comes from the fact that if there is no `htmlcomment`, the number of selected nodes will be one less. The current answer shows what to do when the `htmlcomment` element is present, but empty, but I think you need this instead, if indeed the whole `htmlcomment` element is empty:

```
var testCases = doc.SelectNodes("//testcase");
foreach (XmlElement element in testCases)
{
    var description = element.SelectSingleNode("child::htmlcomment");
    string results = description == null ? "null" : description.Value;
}​
```

In above code, you go over each test case, and select the child node `htmlcomment` of the test case. If not found, `SelectSingleNode` returns `null`, so the last line checks for the result and returns `"null"` in that case, or the node's value otherwise.

To change this result into a node, you will have to create the node as a child to the current node. You said you want an XmlNodeList, so perhaps this works for you:

```
var testCaseDescriptions = doc.SelectNodes("//testcase");
foreach (XmlElement element in testCaseDescriptions)
{
    var comment = element.SelectSingleNode("child::htmlcomment");
    if (comment == null)
    {
        element.AppendChild(
            doc.CreateElement("htmlcomment")
            .AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("none")));
    }
}​
```

After this, the node set is updated.

---

**Note:** apparently, the OP mentions that `element.SelectSingleNode("child::htmlcomment");` does not work, but `element.SelectSingleNode("./htmlcomment");` does, even though technically, these are equal expressions from the point of XPath, and should work according to Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to get the result I wanted (using the second snippet), I only had to change the parameter for SelectSingleNode as it did not give any results.

I changed it into:

var comment = element.SelectSingleNode(@"./htmlcomment");

Comment: @Nicholas, that should have the same effect (`.` merely means _current node_ and is typically a no-op at the beginning of an XPath expression). This may be a bug in the implementation from Microsoft (though I'm surprised). Glad it works!

Comment: I just saw that the 1st htmlcomment contains all the texts of the other htmlcomments while it also doesn't exist and should be "none". Other entries are fine and returning "none" if it's needed but only the 1st record/node is not ok. Any ideas why this only happens to the 1st one?

Comment: @Nicholas, that sounds odd, but try replacing `./htmlcomment` with `./htmlcomment[1]` to force selecting one node. You can also serialize the content (or debug and hover over it) to find what the selected node really looks like.

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Nicholas Then either your XML is different (for instance, a parent `htmlcomment` with underneath other htmlcomments, and/or `testcase` can nest inside itself) or there are parts of your code not shown that cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
var TestCaseDescriptions = doc.SelectNodes("//testcase/htmlcomment");
foreach (XmlElement element in TestCaseDescriptions)
{
    string results = element.Value == null ? "" : element.Value;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but at first it did not return anything. I changed the condition to be element.InnerText == "" ? "Nothing" : element.InnerText; and now it returns the InnerText when there's one but it does not print "Nothing" when the element is missing.

Comment: Btw it seems that Value is always null. When I change the condition to element.Value = null it will print Nothing. ( string results = element.Value == null ? "Nothing" : element.InnerText; )

Comment: Try this : string results = element.Value.Length == 0 ? "Null" : element.InnerText;